# Options for searching PDF / MS Office document content

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongodb-atlas

We have an upcoming project needing the ability to search the content of PDF files and Word documents (also text) and I'm trying to figure out if Atlas search can do this or do we need something like Elasticsearch to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indeed Elasticsearch and its [ingest attachment processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/attachment.html).

You can also look at [FSCrawler](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/).

Disclaimer: author of FSCrawler here ;)

Comment: Thanks, so MongoDB alone can't search PDF / Office docs, correct?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know MongoDb 